# ServiceStack complete noob tutorial

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, servicestack

I have been completely strugling with servicestack. I followed tons of tutorials that I found on google and none works, not even the simple hellotutorial works. Even servicestack's  [tutorials](http://mono.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Hello/#view-webservice) generate errors on my VS project and don't work at all. Also, none of the examples deployed on servicestack's github examples work. I am using Windows 8 and I am totaly noob with VS 2012. I have IIS 8 installed and .Net 4.5. 
I always get 404 errors or 500 or even parse errors. I think it's about documentation that doesn't get updated or configs that change dramatically over the new versions of servicestack. I don't really know.
Can a good soul help me to put a simple API to work with latest version of servicestack (4.0.10) and VS 2012?

Thank you anyways.

Comment: This is not offtopic. This is servicestack related, asking for way to get a project working!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest way to get a complete ServiceStack TODO App running:

1) Create new Empty ASP.NET Web Application

2) Install **ServiceStack.Host.AspNet** and **ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer**

```
PM> Install-Package ServiceStack.Host.AspNet
PM> Install-Package ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer
```

3) Hit **Ctrl + F5** to run the application

4) After playing with the TODO app, view the `http://localhost:{port}/metadata` page

5) Play with the services, e.g `http://localhost:{port}/todos`

6) Look into the source to see how the ServiceStack service is put together, the core parts are:

- **App_Start/AppHost.cs**  (ServiceStack AppHost configuration)
- **App_Start/WebServiceExamples.cs** (The Hello and Todo Services)

When you're comfortable with the example app, go through [creating a ServiceStack service from scratch](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Create-your-first-webservice).

Comment: That worked! Finally, it was the OrmLite Package that was missing all the time. Not a single tutorial that I found had to install that package. Also, you should edit your post and correct "Install" to "Install-Package"

Comment: @JoãoMartins The host packages are a starter template to get up and running with common defaults including registering the Database. I've now added SqlServer to the NuGet dependencies so in the next release it will be imported automatically.